# Why does the mohel fill his mouth with a small amount of wine during the Metzitzah B’peh of a bris?

Tags: brit-milah, grapes-wine, blood

**While not all Jews practice this aspect of circumcision, some include a ritual known as Metzitzah B’peh (the oral suction of blood from the boy's wound)**

I'm aware that the Gemara indicates this was done under the belief it made the procedure healthier and safer for the child. What I'm not aware of is why the mohel puts wine in his mouth before performing the this part of the ritual?

At face value I would assume that this is done to ensure he doesn't accidentally ingest the blood of the child. By adding wine to his mouth he can easily swish it and spit so to not have the child's blood remain after the bris.

That said, I also know wine is alcohol and in modern times we know alcohol can sterilize wounds. Of course, the alcohol percentage in wine may not be strong enough for that purpose so I can't say for certain this is why it was used either.

Is there a definitive answer for why this is done?

Comment: Disinfection, some of them use alcohol-based disinfectants directly instead of wine (see e.g., https://www.nyc.gov/site/doh/health/health-topics/safe-bris.page) and note 23 at https://jewishaction.com/jewish-world/metzitzah_bpeh_rabbinic_polemics/

Comment: AFAIK a lot of models use antiseptic mouthwash prior to metzitzah for sterilization, so the wine doesn't serve that purpose.

Comment: And did they use wine as an antiseptic (or magic disease preventor) in Gemara times?

Comment: It's a mistake. They're supposed to put wine on after the metzitza to stop the bleeding. That is exactly the opposite of what the metzitza is supposed to accomplish which is drawing out the blood. Some mohalim do metzitza without the wine and then put wine in the mouth and go back for a second contact between their mouth and the gid in order to first draw the blood, then stop the blood.